# Insert from another sister table with one extra field

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables and need top copy one to another `INSERT INTO tbl_new SELECT FROM tbl_old`

they both have 3 exact same columns, but tbl_new has 4th column called "type" how can i populate it in the same query.

I need to copy row from tbl_old and assign value to cell "type"

```
INSERT INTO tbl_new SELECT FROM tbl_old, (type) values (floor(rand() * 10))
```

does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say `tbl_old` has two columns and `tbl_new` has three

```
tbl_old
colA | colB

tbl_new
colA | colB | colC
```

Suppose you want to populate colC with sum of colA and colB values. You can use this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_new (colA, colB, colC) SELECT colA,colB,(colA+colB) FROM tbl_old;
```

In your example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_new (colA, colB, colC) SELECT colA,colB,floor(rand()*10) FROM tbl_old;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below :

```
 INSERT INTO tbl_new (column1,column2,column3,type) 
 SELECT column1,column2,column3,floor(rand() * 10) FROM tbl_old
```

Note : replace column1,column1.column3 with your column names.

Answer (score 0):

These answers above are correct, but imagine the time spent writing out columns if everything is identical except for the extra column.

Here is a much neater query if the tables are identical in order with additional column at the end:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_new SELECT *, floor(rand()*10) FROM tbl_old;
```